# Seemly redundant CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, redundancy

I'm dissecting Wordpress's default theme TwentyThirteen in attempts to learn HTML&CSS and more importantly, what I believe to be, industry standards for HTML&CSS.

I ran into a part in the CSS that I believe to be redundant but I would like to some insight on (probably) why the Wordpress team used these 2 CSS selectors together.

```
ul.nav-menu,
div.nav-menu > ul {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Selector

```
ul.nav-menu
```

This first selector relates **only to `ul` elements with a class named `nav-menu`**. For example:

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Here it relates to the `ul` element because it is simply a `ul` with a class of `nav-menu`.

### Second Selector

```
div.nav-menu > ul
```

This second selector relates **only to `ul` elements that are direct children (directly below) `div` elements with a class named `nav-menu`**. For example:

```
<div class="nav-menu">
   <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
   </ul>    
</div>
```

Here it relates to the `ul` within the `div` because it is a `ul` directly below the `div` with a class of `nav-menu`.